# Find four binary relations from $\mathbf{\{a,b\}}$ to $\mathbf{\{x,y\}}$ that are not functions from $\mathbf{\{a,b\}}$ to $\mathbf{\{x,y\}}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

**Question**: Find four binary relations from $\mathbf{\{a,b\}}$ to $\mathbf{\{x,y\}}$ that are not functions from $\mathbf{\{a,b\}}$ to $\mathbf{\{x,y\}}$.

**Thoughts**: I know that a relation $\mathbf R$ from $\mathbf A$ to $\mathbf B$ is the subset of $\mathbf{A \ast B}$, so the possible relations are $\mathbf{2^4 \to 16}$. However, I am stumped when trying to apply the rules for functions to this question. Care to explain?

> To further elaborate, is there a general - intuitive - way of tackling the problem than just writing them all down?

Comment: No, because $\mathbf{b}$ is not accounted for.

Comment: $\{(a, x), (a,y), (b,x)\}$ is one. You have to have one of the elements of $A$ paired with the two elements of $B$.

Comment: @BernardMasse I don't fully understand what you mean. Are you saying that $\mathbf{a}$ must be paired with one of the elements in $\mathbf{ \{x, y\} }$ in order to be a function **or** not a function?

Comment: @AustinMohr So by that logic would  $\mathbf{ \{(a, x)\} }$ be a function? I assumed it wouldn't because every element in set $\mathbf{A}$ there is not an element in $\mathbf{B}$ such that $\mathbf{(x,y) \in F}$, where **F** is the set of functions.

Comment: @LeSunstrike - you appear to overlooking one of the two requirements of a function. Recall that a function can only assign each element of its domain to a *single* element of the codomain. Note that in the examples presented, they are mapping $a$ to *two* elements of $\{x,y\}$. Breaking either the "must map all elements of the domain" or the "each element only maps to one image" rule will prevent it from being a function.

Comment: @PaulSinclair ***Runs into a wall***. Thanks! I was looking at the formal definition, which was confusing me a ton. The next page had the less formal version which was concise with what you noted above. Made it really clear.

Answer (score 1):

(Converting Paul Sinclair's comment to an answer.)

> You appear to overlooking one of the two requirements of a function.
>   Recall that a function can only assign each element of its domain to a
>   single element of the codomain. Note that in the examples presented,
>   they are mapping $a$ to *two* elements of $\{x,y\}$. Breaking either the
>   "must map all elements of the domain" or the "each element only maps
>   to one image" rule will prevent it from being a function.